# Тип данных date возвращает на клиент дату с временем

Tags: sql, postgresql

Тип данных date возвращает на клиент дату с временем. При запросе к бд выводит просто дату.
При отправки данных на клиент, в браузере добавляется время.
Как от него избавиться?
Или поменять запрос к бд, чтобы сразу извлекал дату без времени?

Comment: Это очень странно. в типе date время хранить невозможно, так что не ясно откуда оно там взялось. Но если у вас тип все таки с временем - то да, изменить запрос что бы брал только дату (хотя бы привидением типа к дате `date_column::date`

Comment: Покажите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При извлечении на уровень приложения из БД, например, если на JAVA использовать тип Date, полная дата всегда будет со временем 00:00:00. Для того что бы избавится необходимо решать на уровне преобразования типов из БД в переменную. Либо просто использовать форметер для конкретного отображения.

Так же можно использовать в sql функцию to_char() которая позволит вытащить дату как строку уже в нужном формате.